# Surface PRO 4 Support?

Tags: touchscreen, surface-tablet

I have tried several times to install Juno on a Surface PRO 4 Tablet, most things work great only cam and touch doesn't work, but touch is essential. I have tried to install 'jakeday patch' but the touch only works for a moment then it died.
Would be great if there's a better SP4 device support.

Greetings Mark